# Para que serve função super();

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança, objetos

Estou estudando Java e preciso entender a lógica de um código aqui. Queria saber o que esse trecho de código faz:

```
public class UsuarioController extends HttpServlet {
    private DAO dao;    

    public UsuarioController() {
        super();
    }...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O `super()` serve para chamar o construtor da superclasse. Ele sempre é chamado, mesmo quando não está explícito no código, quando for explicitado deve ser o primeiro item dentro do construtor.

Veja por exemplo o código abaixo:

```
public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sub();
    }
}

class Super {
    public Super() {
        System.out.println("super");
    }
}

class Sub extends Super {
    public Sub() {
        System.out.println("sub");
    }
}
```

Saída:

> super
>   sub

Apesar da classe Teste estar instanciando um objeto da classe Sub, tanto os construtores de Sub e de Super são chamados.

Answer (score 5):

No Java `super()` invoca o constructor, sem argumentos, da classe derivada (pai).

No teu exemplo, e uma vez que `UsuarioController` extende a classe `HttpServlet` irá invocar o construtor *default* da classe `HttpServlet`.

A diretiva `super`, sem parênteses, permite ainda invocar métodos da classe que foi derivada através da seguinte syntax.

```
super.metodo();
```

Isto é útil nos casos em que faças *override* (sobrescrevas) um método da classe pai e desejas invocar o método *original*.

Answer (score 2):

Quando trabalhamos com herança a *superclasse* é a classe que herdamos e sub classe é a classe que herda da superclasse.

A subclasse pode sobrescrever métodos da superclasse e, claro, implementar seus próprios métodos. Cada classe possui duas referências: o **this**, que referencia a instância dela mesma e o **super** que referencia a *superclasse*.

Na prática funciona assim:

```
public class Pessoa {
  private String nome;      

  public Pessoa() {
     // Construtor padrão. 
  }

  public Pessoa(String nome) {
     this.nome = nome; // Aqui fazemos referência a instância da classe
  }

  public void chorar() {
    System.out.print("Pessoa chorando");
  }

  public void greet() {
     System.out.print("Olá "+this.nome);
  }
}

public class Chaves extends Pessoa {
  public void chorar() {
    System.out.print("pi pi pi pi pi pi pi ");
    super.chorar(); // Aqui eu invoco o método da superclasse se eu quiser.
  }
}
```

Note que a classe pessoa tem um método `greet()`, que é acessível publicamente em qualquer instância de `Pessoa` e suas subclasses, só que `nome`só é acessível pelo construtor de `Pessoa`, e agora? Simples: Basta alterar o construtor de `Chaves`, desta forma:

```
public Chaves() {
  super("Chaves"); // Lembra que temos um construtor com argumentos em Pessoa?
}
```

Eu posso chamar outros métodos da superclasse também:

```
public foo() {
  this.fazAlgumaCoisa();
  super.fazOutraCoisa(); 
  /* também é possível usar this.fazOutraCoisa(). Se eu não sobrescrever o           
     método fazOutraCoisa eu prefiro usar o super, deixando claro que este
     método está na superclasse. Faço assim para facilitar  aleitura*/
}
```

Algumas coisa interessantes que devemos saber sobre o `super`é o seguinte:

**Ao declarar uma classe sem o construtor padrão (Sem argumentos) a jvm cria um para você da seguinte maneira:**

```
public Classe() {
  super(); // Aqui o super chama o construtor da superclasse;
}
```

**Quando falamos de construtores, o `super()` deve sempre ser o primeiro método a ser chamado:**

```
public Classe() {
   this.fazAlgumaCoisa();
   super(); // erro de compilação
}


public Classe() {
   super(); // Ok
   this.fazAlgumaCoisa(); //OK
}
```

**O uso do super não é obrigatório e é de boa prática fazer o uso correto dele para facilitar a leitura do código. Seguem abaixo algumas recomendações:**

- Devemos chamar o construtor da `superclasse`apenas se fizer sentido. Fazer isso deixa claro para outros programadores: *Ei, tem coisa importante acontecendo na superclasse. Fica esperto!*
- Os métodos que são herdados e não sobrescritos nunca devem ser invocados usando `this.metodoHerdado()`, prefira `super.metodoHerdado()`. Isso vai deixar claro para outros programadores que este método está implementado na *superclasse* e não na classe em que ele está trabalhando. Isto é apenas uma recomendação.

Comment: Não sou estudioso de OOP, mas acho a segunda recomendação meio estranha. Isso não seria recomendado somente nos casos em que a subclasse faz override do método, como dito na [resposta do @bruno](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66565/)?

Comment: @bfavaretto Não necessáriamente. Entenda o seguinte: Se eu estiver usando um método da super classe que não foi sobrecarregado eu posso usar tanto o this quanto o super, terei o mesmo resultado. Entretando usar o super deixa claro para outras pessoas que este método esta na super classe (imagine uma classe bem grande, ele não vai perder tempo procurando). É só pra leitura mesmo, nada mais...

Answer (score 1):

Serve para chamar o construtor da classe pai da classe que está chamando o `super();` Pode também ser chamado com parâmetros caso a classe pai possuir um construtor com o devido parâmetro, como `super(parametro);`

No seu caso irá chamar o construtor `HttpServlet()` da classe pai.

Para estudar bem para a prova, leia o manual do java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html